# Stack-essence of the acion

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have a defined `stack` with `integers`.

In the following case of using If:`if(stack.pop>number)`

The capacity of the following stacked, will it automatically reduce?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to see if the amount of space in the stack grows or shrinks with removal of items. Since there are multiple ways to implement a stack data structure, there are multiple answers to your question. In a Fixed Size Arrray implementation, once you allocate the array that you want to be filled that is all the capacity you have. While in a Dynamic Array implementation, you can create a certain array size `x` but to have it grow or shrink you must call another method to change the array size. Finally a Linked List implementation you can have it grow or shrink as much as you want with the head of the linked list being the top of the stack.

[Reference](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/241/241notes/241stk.htm)